# while sending the data to text field using appium its working as longpress

Tags: appium

driver1.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText")).get(1).sendKeys("santhosh");
        driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: while sending the data to text field using appium its working as longpress